# How to reduce size of data in laravel for ajax response?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am fetching data from database which is returning almost 5000 records form database . when I see resource size over network it is `10 mb` of size.

This table has almost fifty columns. Is there any way I can reduce the size which displaying in network tab of browser?

here is the query

```
$consignments = Consignment::query();
$consignments->where('delivery_run_id', null);
  
$consignments = $consignments->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5000)->get();

return Response::json(['status' => 'success', 'consignment' => $consignments]);
```

i try to use `select()` but no effect

Comment: You have used `select()` for specific field?

Comment: yes for example o `id`

Comment: try this `get(['id']);`

Comment: use pagination https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way. I just select the column which was required for ajax response and ignored all other column and now I successfully reduced data from `10mb` to `2.5mb`

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$consignments = $consignments->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5000)->select(['column one','column two','column three']);
```